# Where do I find the values for the required parameters in the ActiveCollab API issue-token-intent endpoint?

Tags: activecollab

I am struggling to find references in the ActiveCollab API documentation to aspects of the issue-token-intent endpoint, namely the `intent`, `client_name`, and `client_vendor` parameters.

This is the guide I have been following: https://gist.github.com/Elvis339/c66104950d0a7801ef544869786d2c77, with the issue being on step 2. I was able to get step 1 to work as expected, but I don't see how any of the values returned relate to step 2.

My end goal is to get an access/authorisation token. Any help would be greatly appreciated - hopefully I've just missed something in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled with getting a token as well. Below is a single curl command that was successful in returning a token. I am on a self-hosted install.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://<SELF HOSTED URL>/api/v7/issue-token'
--header 'Content-Type: application/json'
--data-raw '{
"username": "<USERNAME>",
"password": "<PASSWORD>",
"client_name": "<ARBITRARY IDENTIFYING NAME>",
"client_vendor": "<ARBITRARY IDENTIFYING VENDOR>"
}'
`
```

I believe the gist you referenced may be out of date. Based on the [current API documentation](https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/v1/authentication.html), the `/issue-token` endpoint should be used. I found the API to accept arbitrary values for both `client_name` and `client_vendor`.